# Magento 2 - Override title.phtml with custom attribute value

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, title

CURRENT STATE:

Custom theme installed

Title of the product in the product details page displays the product name

In backend: Made new custom attribute (brand), put it to default attribute set, added some values

DESIRED STATE:

Product title on the product details page displays BRAND + NAME

---

I tried changing title.phtml from vendor > magento > module-theme > view > frontend > templates > html > title.phtml but I cannot get the value of custom attribute no matter how I try (I can only set some static value instead of $title but no real/dynamic values for each product).

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved your issue by creating a frontend plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title">
        <plugin name="product_title" type="Mbs\Title\Plugin\ProductTitleWithBrand" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and then the plugin reads whether the page title to render is for a product registered in the registry as per product detail view.

```
class ProductTitleWithBrand
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $_coreRegistry;

    private static $attributePrefix = 'brand';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $_coreRegistry;
    }

    public function afterGetPageHeading(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title $subject, $title)
    {
        if ($this->getProduct()) {
            $prefix = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText(self::$attributePrefix);
            if ($prefix) {
                $title = $prefix.' '.$title;
            }
        }

        return $title;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve currently viewed product object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    private function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
    }
}
```

see full code at https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/mbstitle

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much Herve, it works! I'd give you 100 upvotes if I could :) Cheers!