# Magento2: How to get custom_name on product page

Tags: magento2

Currently our product page display product title from attribute: `name`
https://prnt.sc/t8p3so

I want change and display above title: Brand name from attribute: `newbrand_name` and under brand Name I want display title (product name) from custom attribute `custom_name`

Here I see similar question:
[Magento 2 - Override title.phtml with custom attribute value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238063/magento-2-override-title-phtml-with-custom-attribute-value)

Can any one help customization code?

Comment: what issue you faced using that answer?

Comment: Because this module display: BRAND + NAME. We need display: BRAND + NAME from custom  attribute with code: custom_name

Comment: @Rohan, do you have maybe any solution?